# Editing application in Ollydbg

Tags: out-of-memory, reverse-engineering, instructions, ollydbg

I have a question that need clarification.
When I change the `JNZ` instruction to `JE` the application runs in `Ollydbg 1.10` perfectly. But when I close `Ollydbg` and click on the file that I changed, it pops a message which says `The file seems to be corrupt.` Why is this happening?

Comment: This could happen if the file is compressed.